# Requirements issues while setting up a D7 website

Tags: 7, installation

I'm trying to set up an old D7 website, but I stumble upon some issues.

As you can see in the image below, I work with PHP 5.4.8 and Apache 4.2.3.

I don't use things like XAMPP. I've configured Apache, MySQL and PHP myself on my Windows 7 machine.

[image]

In my `php.ini`-file I've enabled all the necessary extensions I believe...:

```
extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
extension=php_imap.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_pgsql.dll
```

But still, I get the errors above. What should I do next?

Comment: Did you restart Apache?

Comment: @MPD, several times, but with no luck...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing some PHP components.

Try the following on the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install php-gd php5-common php5-mysql
sudo service apache reload
```

**EDIT**

I've just realised I've COMPLETELY assumed you're running *buntu - if you're not then please let me know!

Comment: Indeed :) In this case, I'm using a locale Windows 7 environment

Comment: Are you using WAMP or XAMPP or the like?

Comment: Nope, just a custom Apache, PHP, MySQL set-up

Comment: You're probably going to want to head over to [PHP:  Installation of extensions on Windows](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php) for some help then.  Seems like everything you need is there :)

Comment: So according to you, my settings should work but there is something else which blocks the Drupal installation process?

Comment: It's possible that although you're referencing the extensions, they're not ACTUALLY there.  I don't think PHP GD is *part* of PHP 5.x, so that'll need installing.  PHP MySql was removed from PHP by default from 5.0.4 onwards.

Comment: Pretty sure @Chapabu's last comment is on the mark.  You should see if those DLLs actually exist, and also check the PHP logs to see if there were any startup errors.  You should also make a page with <?php phpinfo(); ?> in it to see what extensions are really present.